# Item Level security - Custom List - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: security, sharepoint-2010

I have looked at all articles I can find on this but not found a straightforward answer.

I have a custom list....I want it so that only one user can answer a specific question item in this list, I don't mind whether other users can see this question or not (but they should be able to edit it).
Can someone advise me of the easiest way to do this?
SharePoint foundation 2010 is platform.

Comment: Is the list a discussion board?

Comment: give item level permissions, contribute to the users who should reply and read to all others. you can create a view in list which will display only my items.

Comment: It is a custom list. I need 1Q - "decision of head of operations" (procede/don't procede) to only be editable by 1 person (on all items created on the list). How can I do that for a single Q for all items created?? I can see how to set permissions for the entire list, but not for 1 question when any item added.  Basically,1 question in all items can only be answered by 1 specific user. I need everyone to be able to update all items (bar this field) as a case progresses (except for this one question in all cases, which can only be answered by the head of operations). Is this possible?